# JavaFX FileChooser ExtensionFilter not working properly- Highlighted Files

Tags: javafx, file-extension, filechooser

I am trying to use the extension filter on javafx's file chooser to limit the user's choice to pdfs and tiffs. This aspect works just fine, but when i open the file chooser, the first added extension filter is used and these files are highlighted. This is also fine, but when i select a different filter, the highlighted files will not change. If i am in the pdf filter, choose a pdf file, then change filters that file will become disabled, but none others. I am guessing this is an internal issue with javafx but i figured I would check to see if anyone else has had this issue. I am also using osx not sure if that would affect this. here is the code I am using for the file chooser:

```
    try
                    {
                        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                        fileChooser.setTitle("select a file");

                        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.jpeg", "*.pdf", "*.tiff"),
                                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPEG (*.JPEG, *.jpeg)", "*.jpeg", "*.JPEG"),
                                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF (*.PDF, *.pdf)", "*.pdf","*.PDF"),
                                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TIF (*.tif, *.tiff)", "*.tif", "*.tiff"));

                        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(workbench.getStage());
```

I have used a filter containing most of my file types so that all files are highlighted to begin. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I tried and your code worked here, you may try the `FileChooserBuilder()` but I believe it may not work on your case, if so update your question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I will update my answer.

Take care on Unix GNU/Linux as they file names are case sensitive there, this may also have a huge impact if you don't handle it properly.

```
FileChooserBuilder fcb = FileChooserBuilder.create();
FileChooser fc = fcb.title("Open Dialog").build();

//Set extension filter
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterALL = 
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.jpeg", "*.jpg", "*.pdf",
                "*.tiff", "*.tif","*.JPG","*.JPEG", "*.PDF", "*.TIFF", "*.TIF");
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = 
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG", "*.jpg",
                                        "*.JPEG", "*.jpeg");
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPDF = 
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF files (*.pdf)", "*.PDF", "*.pdf");
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterTIFF =
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TIFF files (*.tiff)", "*.TIF", "*.TIFF",
                                        "*.tif", "*.tiff");

fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterALL,extFilterJPG, extFilterPDF, extFilterTIFF);

File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
```

Comment: `FileChooserBuilder` is @deprecated